# Loading views into template without Ajax on Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Good evening people. I have this Django question.. I have a view that renders a form with a header information from a master-detail like models. Below this form, I want to load another view that renders a form that fills the detail table and next to it, the list with the detail. I want to load inside the template of the header view, the detail's view but I want to do it without ajax. I was reading the {% include %} tag but, from what I understand, it loads a template, not a view. I might be wrong, is there a way to load a view inside the master's template?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't render a view like that without ajax. `{% load %}` is used for loading modules, not templates or views, like:

```
{% load humanize %}
```

However, you could use an `{% include %}` tag, or a custom template tag that does whatever processing you need and returns its template where you include it.

Comment: Rite, I was wrong then, {% include %} isn't intended for templates only? As I read, you can use {% include foo/bar.html %} How can you include a view with {% include %}?

Comment: You won't be able to include a view. If you're needing to do some processing based on values present in the request context, you can do so with a custom template tag.

Comment: Ok. gottt it.. is there a reason why it can't be done? thanks btw

Comment: Views are intended to return an HttpResponse.

Comment: Don't be intimidated by writing a custom template tag, it's actually very easy to do, and you can do anything you can do in Python within a template tag.

Comment: Kewl. You should post an edit to your question showing what you came up with to help users in the future.